# Requisição AJAX no Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, bootstrap-3

Olá

Eu estou precisando abrir uma pagina externa por meio de uma requisição AJAX na minha ROW no Bootstrap, mas não estou tendo sucesso, eu estou seguindo o tutorial do link abaixo, mas não esta abrindo a minha pagina na ROW do Bootstrap, como eu posso fazer ? Tem alguma função nativa do Bootstrap para isso ?

http://tedk.com.br/blog/html/carregar-uma-pagina-dentro-de-uma-div-com-ajax/

Código:

```
    <!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>load demo</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <style>
        body {
        font-size: 12px;
        font-family: Arial;
        }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>

    <b>Projects:</b>
    <div id="new-projects" style="width:400px, height:400px"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $( "#new-projects" ).html('<object data="https://pt.stackoverflow.com"/>');
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Obrigado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use isto:

```js
$( "#new-projects" ).html('<object data="https://pt.stackoverflow.com"/>');
```

```css
  body {
    font-size: 12px;
    font-family: Arial;
  }
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>load demo</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 
<b>Projects:</b>
<div id="new-projects"></div>
 
 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Eu sei o seu código, mas não esta rodando, porque ?

Comment: Veja se está carregando o jQuery. Uma pergunta, a página é externa, outro domínio?

Comment: Então, Esta aparecendo isso no meu console ( Refused to display 'https://pt.stackoverflow.com/' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'.
pt.stackoverflow.com/ Failed to load resource: net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_RESPONSE
/favicon.ico Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) )

Comment: E eu botei seu script acima em um host online. Mas não funciona.

Comment: O motivo é o domínio. Ex: se estou em www.meusite.com eu posso chamar www.meusite.com/outrapagina, mas se chamar www.google.com por segurança não permite.

Comment: Que legal. Agora deu certo. Obrigado.